# psycopg2 - Using SQL object with execute_values

Tags: python, sql, database, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm inserting data using execute_values, which takes a sql query. The query is constructed using psycopg2.sql.SQL as recommended in the documentation, but execute_values won't take that object.

Here's the code I have:

```
import psycopg2 as pg
from psycopg2 import extras
from psycopg2 import sql

config = {
    'host' : 'localhost',
    'user' : 'username',
    'password' : 'password',
    'dbname' : 'myDatabase'
}

connection = pg.connect(**config)
cursor = connection.cursor()

tableName = 'myTable'
dataset = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]

queryText = "INSERT INTO {table} (uid,value) VALUES %s"
query = sql.SQL(queryText).format(table=sql.Identifier(tableName))

extras.execute_values(cursor,query,dataset)
```

The last line gives the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Composed' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

If the query is specified directly as a string, as below, then the execution runs.

```
query = """INSERT INTO "myTable" (uid,value) VALUES %s"""
```

It's possible to insert the table name into the query using string format, but apparently that [shouldn't be done, even at gunpoint](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#the-problem-with-the-query-parameters). How can I safely insert a variable table name into the query and use execute_values? I can't find a built-in way to convert the SQL object to a string.

Comment: which line is giving you the error?

Comment: I think one of the reasons it doesn't work is because it's usually something that shouldn't be done. You should know into which table you're inserting data. Seems to me like maybe you're trying to use sql database as a key-value database, which means you're trying to use it in a way it's not meant to be used? Could you please explain why are you trying to do that or what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @pacuna - the last line gives the error. The "object" being referred to is query, which cannot be encoded like a string because it doesn't have that method

Comment: @JanSpurny - The script is being used to import data from a file into a table selected by the user. This is normal operation for psycopg2, see http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html. The problem is that the query checking of pscycopg2.sql doesn't extend to the multi-values execution.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The parameter `sql` in [`execute_values(cur, sql, argslist, template=None, page_size=100)`](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#psycopg2.extras.execute_values) is supposed to be a string:

> sql – the query to execute. It must contain a single %s placeholder, which will be replaced by a VALUES list. Example: "INSERT INTO mytable (id, f1, f2) VALUES %s".

Use the [`as_string(context)`](http://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html#psycopg2.sql.Composable) method:

```
extras.execute_values(cursor, query.as_string(cursor), dataset)
connection.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

As [`execute_values()`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#fast-execution-helpers) expect the sql statement to be a string you can simply user:

```
 queryText = "INSERT INTO {table} (uid,value) VALUES %s".format(table=sql.Identifier(tableName)
```